# How to fix the Accessible Label Error on Powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I am new on using the powerapps, I tried to make a app from the sample Data as Asset Checkout.

After the all done, I tried to run App Checker but it showed errors "Missing Accessible Label". Trying to find the solutions from the Search Engine but unfortunately I can't find it (AccessibleLabel filled `""`).

Anyone know how to fix this, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These missing accessible label errors do not interfere with running app. To fix that errors you have to put some text that describes the item into ***AccessibleLabel*** field of your control. People who can’t see the screen can understand what is in controls.

Comment: Thx mate, this fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

`AccessibleLabel` is one of the properties for PowerApps controls that will help with accessibility. Its value is what screen readers will read out loud, and is quite important for visually impaired users.

You can find more information about it at https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/properties-accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

The best was to resolve is to add a tooltip

Self.Tooltip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qoB7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).